# I have a Belker router and i am looking for a tool that monitors the ports and reports whitch ports are opend

Tags: port, port-forwarding, network-monitoring

I have a Belker router and i am looking for a tool that monitors the ports and reports whitch ports are opend. I need it for testing an aplication. Could you recomend a good offline monitoring tool?. And what kind of router do i need to test with a Berlker router.

In the first stage of testing i just need to test witch ports are opend on a router, sow if i can't monitor at least i need to test for opend ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nmap http://nmap.org/ .

You can scan for open ports with 
nmap -sV 192.168.2.1

Where 192.168.2.1 is your router IP.
-sV will find the version of the service running on each port

"Nmap ("Network Mapper") is a free and open source (license) utility for network discovery and security auditing. Many systems and network administrators also find it useful for tasks such as network inventory, managing service upgrade schedules, and monitoring host or service uptime. Nmap uses raw IP packets in novel ways to determine what hosts are available on the network, what services (application name and version) those hosts are offering, what operating systems (and OS versions) they are running, what type of packet filters/firewalls are in use, and dozens of other characteristics. It was designed to rapidly scan large networks, but works fine against single hosts. Nmap runs on all major computer operating systems, and official binary packages are available for Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X. In addition to the classic command-line Nmap executable, the Nmap suite includes an advanced GUI and results viewer (Zenmap), a flexible data transfer, redirection, and debugging tool (Ncat), a utility for comparing scan results (Ndiff), and a packet generation and response analysis tool (Nping). "